# Updating to 10.14.6 giving internet connection error

Tags: software-update

While trying to download the update for my Mac, I am getting an error which indicates there is a problem with my internet connection. My internet connection is working fine, however. Tried using the default Software Update and also using the command line. Command line error below.

MacOs Mojave 10.14.5

```
sudo softwareupdate -i -a

Password:
Software Update Tool

Finding available software

Downloading macOS 10.14.6 Update
Downloaded macOS 10.14.6 Update
Preparing macOS 10.14.6 Update
Error downloading macOS 10.14.6 Update: An Internet connection is required to install macOS.
Done.

Error downloading updates.
```

[image: error]

Comment: Please edit or comment with the specific Mac model. You might also try installing the update if you download it instead of using the built-in software update methods. The Mojave 10.14.6 update is available here: https://support.apple.com/kb/DL2011?locale=en_US

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd download the full combo updater from a web browser - that way you *should* be OK through retries & you know that you have the entire file safely on your Mac before committing to the actual update.

Google can always find these easily, using 'combo update 10.14.6' & it will always be first hit.

https://support.apple.com/kb/DL2010

Comment: This installation is also giving the Internet required at the final step.

Comment: hmm... I wonder if it would behave differently if it **knows** it can't get a connection - unplug ethernet, turn off wifi... otherwise, best I could say would be try again tomorrow, see if it's at their end, servers busy perhaps. iOS update came at the same time.

Comment: I turned off my internet and then it's showing. "An error occurred while installing the update."

Comment: ach - I'm out of ideas, sorry :\

Comment: Is there a way to re-download the update again?

Comment: The download itself doesn't seem to be the issue - it's some later online check that looks like it's being blocked somewhere. Make sure your firewall at least allows everything in & out on the 17.x.x.x block, as that's *all* Apple. Also, by domain, apple.com, cdn-apple.com, mzstatic.com

Answer (score 2):

For me, turning off Malwarebytes fixed it. (Just deauthorizing it is sufficient; no need to uninstall.) Turning it back on after updating didn't cause any problem.

Answer (score -1):

I disabled Lulu and it worked.

Comment: What is Lulu?  How does it relate to the OP's question and finally how did you disable it?  See [How to write a good answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) for tips on writing an answer that will get attention and ultimately up voted.

Comment: Google Lulu - it's a firewall. It's related to the Q b/c it solved my problem which was that same Q. Mac swr update was failing b/c updater was blocked by firewall.